# How to get rid of the bottom line in the navigation menu via CSS file?

Tags: menus, css

How do I eliminate the bottom line in the nav menu - shown in the pic by the red arrow - which separates the menu from the body of the page? I made different attempts with CSS to no avail, and any suggestion I have found didn't help either. Please help! Thank you.

[image: grey bar to eliminate is indicated by red arrow]
Here is the current CSS code:

```
#access a {
    color: #000 !important;
    display: block;     font-weight: normal !important;
    line-height: 1.533em;
    padding: 0 0.8125em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#access ul ul {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3.333em;
    left: 0;
    width: 188px;
    z-index: 99999;
}
#access ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Need more info then what you have provided. Link?

Comment: Can’t provide link. However, this is a mildly modified child theme based on the Twenty Eleven theme. The bar I’m referring to is part of any Twenty Eleven theme, hence knowing how to remove it from there would address my problem. Thanks

Comment: find `#access` and Remove `box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)` may be this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Though you have not mentioned much details. But from shared details possible solution is - you just need to remove box-shadow from `nav`